# why is a for loop not appending a list

Tags: python, list, loops

In the below code, the loops don't seem to be working.

```
powers = []
x = 0
y = 0
z = 1

for x in powers:
powers.append([])
for y in powers[x]:
    powers[x].append(z ** y)
    z = z + 1
    if z < 1001:
        continue
    else:
        break
x = x + 1
y = y + 1
z = 1
print(powers)
```

However, when I run this in the terminal, it simply returns an empty list for powers. It doesn't show an error message.

Please help.

Comment: Please start by correcting indentation of your `for` loops. Note `for x in powers` (where `powers = []`), will do nothing. Please supply a [mcve].

Comment: for y in powers[x]. This line will definitely throw you an error.

Comment: Never heard aof DEBUGGERS? I strongly suggest you to use one of those to understand where your problem are

Comment: Also: is not even clear what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is badly formatted, so please consider formatting, anyway some of your errors are code-comments.

```
powers = []
x = 0
y = 0
z = 1

for x in powers: #here you're overriding former declaration of x, also powers is empty so for doesn't have a single run
powers.append([]) ##code is not indented so this istruction execute only once
for y in powers[x]: ##powers[x] is an empty list
        powers[x].append(z ** y)
        z = z + 1
        if z < 1001:
            continue
        else:
            break
z = 1 ## this is outside the cycle 
x = x + 1 
y = y + 1 

print(powers)
```